# jPlayer - "ready" event isn't firing in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

Like the title says, I have a script that is working in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. A couple unique things to this implementation are: 1) Multiple versions of jQuery (using noConflict), and 2) the majority of the assets used by jPlayer are generated through the script.

**The Markup**

```
<a class="audio-trigger" data-type="mp3" data-loop="false" href="/path.to.mp3">Listen</a>
```

**The JS (inside a document.ready function)**

```
// Initialize audio 
if ($('.audio-trigger').length) {

    //get jQuery 1.10.2 for jPlayer
    $.getScript('/rsc/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', function () {
        $.getScript('/rsc/js/libs/jplayer-2.5.0.min.js', function () {

            //jPlayer noConflict option is restricted to strings that contain the term jQuery
            var jQuery1102 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            console.log('jQuery ' + $.fn.jquery + ' has been restored to global, and jQuery ' + jQuery1102.fn.jquery + ' has been preserved.');

            //create pause button and audio container
            var pause = '<a class="audio-pause" href="javascript:;">Pause | <span class="audio-currentTime"></span> / <span class="audio-duration"></span></a><div class="audio-play-area"></div>';
            jQuery1102('.audio-trigger').after(pause);

            //get audio link
            var audioLink = jQuery1102('.audio-trigger').attr('href');

            //Init jPlayer
            jQuery1102('.audio-play-area').jPlayer( {
                ready: function() {
                    jQuery1102(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
                        mp3: audioLink
                    });
                },
                swfPath: '/rsc/js/libs',
                supplied: jQuery1102('.audio-trigger').data('type'),
                cssSelectorAncestor: '',
                cssSelector: {
                    play: '.audio-trigger',
                    pause: '.audio-pause',
                    currentTime: '.audio-currentTime',
                    duration: '.audio-duration'
                },
                noConflict: 'jQuery1102',
                loop: jQuery1102('.audio-trigger').data('loop'),
                errorAlerts: true
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and lastly, when I click on the audio trigger...
**The Error**

```
Attempt to issue media playback commands, while no media url is set. 
Use setMedia() to set the media URL 
Context: play
```

My .swf path name is 100% accurate and there are no other errors being thrown in any browser.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the .swf on the server was out of date. Updating it fixed the issue. Womp womp.